# Object Oriented Model original paper?

Tags: oop

It would be fascinating to read the original paper where the Object Oriented Model as we understand it today was first proposed (equivalent to Edgar Codd's proposal of the relational model).

I wasn't able to find it because it seems several people informally used it without referring to a common citation.

Does anyone know which paper originally proposed it, if there was one?

Comment: "as we understand it?" -- reminds me of the Alan Kay quote:  “I was the one who coined the term (object-oriented), and C++ was not what I had in mind!”

Comment: AFAIK, there was no original paper like there was with the relational model. The earliest example of which I'm aware was a format used with tapes on Burroughs mainframes. Unlike IBM tapes that started with a "label" that defined the data format, it started with pointers to functions to use to read, write, etc., the data on that tape. It's known to have originated in the US Air Force, but nobody seems sure exactly who first did it.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. All of them have useful information.

Comment: Surely how is this off-topic? knowing the frame of mind and the thinking of the inventors of a solution is essential to understanding the problem and the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the object oriented paradigm was being used quite regularly for several years before the term "Object-oriented" was coined.  Thus, there is no paper on the concept because everyone was familiar with it when the term came into being.

Prior to that they just called it by the languages.. simula, smalltalk, etc..

It's like the term "Singleton".  The concept was around for years before the GoF coined the term and enshrined it in the Patterns book.

Answer (score 1):

According to my university sources (scripts) it was in 1966, when SIMULA was created by O. J. Dahl and K. Nygaard (term "class" was declared). Another language was Smalltalk-72 (Alan Kay and Adele Goldberg) few years later.

Comment: Is there a paper accompanying the introduction of Simula?

Comment: google

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simula